# Не могу подключиться к базе данных, пожалуйста помогите

Tags: java

```html
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    private static final String url =
       "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:/Users/Senko_KL/Desktop/base/LAWYERS_PORTAL.fdb?lc_ctype=WIN1251&user=sysdba&password=masterkey";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from lawyers-portal");
        while (resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println(resultSet);
        }
    }
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.github.steed777</groupId>
    <artifactId>connectdatabase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
                <artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
        <artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

вылезает ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: unsupported on-disk
>   structure for file C:\USERS\SENKO_KL\DESKTOP\BASE\LAWYERS_PORTAL.FDB;
>   found 24578.3, support 11.2 [SQLState:HY000, ISC error code:335544379]

пробовал разные версии firebird и разные зависимости, но безуспешно.
версия firebird: 2.5.9.27139

Comment: https://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=1010363&msg=14043298?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открывал базу данных сервером firebird, а нужно было redbase